# PHP - Переопределить метод, которому передается неопределенное кол-во ссылок

Tags: php, классы

Что важно, PHP < 5.6.

Есть метод класса, например, mysqli_stmt::bind_result(). Ему передается динамическое кол-во ссылок на переменные.

Я расширяю класс mysqli_stmt под свои нужды, но при переопределении bind_result я столкнулся с проблемой: как моему методу получить эти ссылки?

Будь это обычные переменные, можно было бы применить func_get_args(), передавать с аргументы с & я тоже не могу т.к. "Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed" (что очень зря).

В PHP 5.6 можно делать такое:

```
function foo(&...args)
```

А какие аналоги есть в более ранних версиях?

Answer (score 4):

Если в кратце то расширят данный класс - плохое архетектурное решение. 
Обнавление ПХП становится смертельно опасным для приложения. И неслабо усложняется тестирование.

Гораздо лучше передавать mysqli_stmt для работы в другой класс (через DI).

**Например:**

Было:

```
<?php 
    class Test extends mysqli_stmt
    {
    }
```

Стало:

```
<?php

class Test
{
    public function setMysqlStmt(mysqli_stmt $stmt) 
    {
        $this->_stmt = $stmt;
    }

    public function __call($name, $args)
    {
        call_user_func_array([$this->_stmt, $name], $args);
    }
}

$myStmt = new Test();
$myStmt->setMysqlStmt($stmt);
$myStmt->bind_result($a, $b, $c /*Any amount of parameters*/);
```

Comment: А если я потом захочу обратиться к методу изначального класса stmt, то мне делать ->_stmt->метод? Слишком длинно и неудобно. Или мне реализовать все методы старого stmt в новом? Ещё хуже. Именно для этого и нужно расширение. И, к слову, в решении проблемы с передачей параметров вы мне не помогли. Ответ не по теме

Comment: Я раньше тоже так думал ;)

Comment: Даже используй я ваш совет, как мне принять неопределённое количество ссылок и передать в функцию? Т.к. мне НУЖНО это сделать

Comment: call_user_func_array

Comment: Динамические параметры передаются в функцию по значению, а не по ссылке. Передать то функция передаст, но что? Она передаст значения в этом случае

Comment: @user64675 обнавил свой ответ.

Comment: @user64675 Поправил пример. Добавил overload __call  функцию теперь будет работать прозрачно как и  mysqli_stmt . Только надо будет написать только функции что меняються.

Comment: array $vars - не работает. Argument 1 passed to ... must be of the type array. В том, чтобы передать массив ссылок, нет ничего сложного, но удобство это нарушает. Я имею ввиду именно bind_result($arg0, $arg1...)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33995/discussion-between-e-p-and-user64675).